# How to abort a Task in JavaFX?

Tags: multithreading, javafx, concurrency

Is it possible to abort a `Task` in JavaFX? My `Task` could run into situations where I want to cancel the rest of the operations within it.

I would need to return a value, somehow, so I can handle the cause of the abort in the JFX Application Thread.

Most of the related answers I've seen refer to handling an already-canceled Task, but now how to manually cancel it from within the Task itself.

The `cancel()` method seems to have no effect as both messages below are displayed:

```
public class LoadingTask<Void> extends Task {

    @Override
    protected Object call() throws Exception {

        Connection connection;

        // ** Connect to server ** //
        updateMessage("Contacting server ...");
        try {
            connection = DataFiles.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            updateMessage("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            cancel();
            return null;
        }

        // ** Check user access ** //
        updateMessage("Verifying user access ...");
        try {
            String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
            ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(
                    SqlQueries.SELECT_USER.replace("%USERNAME%", username));

            // If user doesn't exist, block access
            if (!resultSet.next()) {

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your task has to cooperate with the `canceled` flag. This is explained in detail in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) (the paragraph beginning "In Java there is no reliable way to 'kill' a thread in process.") There are also several examples on that page. It's not really clear what you want to do from the `call()` method itself that you wouldn't do with "normal logic" (e.g. just have a `return` statement, instead of, or as well as, a call to `cancel()`).

Comment: You could do this by throwing a (custom?) exception that contains the necessary info. This will change the state of the task to `FAILED` and make the exception available via the `Task.exception` property...

Comment: @james_d the code I posted isn't complete; just a sample of the flow. I do have a lot more code to be processed in the task. I will reread the paragraph you referenced as I could not quite understand it the first time.

Comment: Even if it's just an example, the point is you have to implement the flow of the logic yourself. I.e. if the task is canceled, don't perform any additional parts of the `call()` method. Simply calling `cancel()` isn't magically going to change the rules of flow control in Java.

Comment: Probably you need to post a slightly more realistic example. The solution to the problem you state, in the context of the example you're using, is of course just to omit the second call to `updateMessage(...)` entirely.

Comment: @James_D I updated the code in my question. Essentially, for this example, I do not want to finish executing the Task if the database connection fails.

What fabian suggested seems to be the best way to interrupt it, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in this case you should just rethrow the exception. I probably wouldn't even set the message in this case, in which case you can just remove the `try` and the entire catch block. Then if the connection fails, the exception is thrown by the `call()` method and the task enters a `FAILED` state. You can use a `setOnFailed` on the task, and call `getException` in that handler if you need to know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just let the task go into a `FAILED` state if it fails? All you need (I also corrected the errors with the type of the task and return type of the call method) is

```
public class LoadingTask extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        Connection connection;

        // ** Connect to server ** //
        updateMessage("Contacting server ...");
        connection = DataFiles.getConnection();

        // ** Check user access ** //
        updateMessage("Verifying user access ...");
        String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
        ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(
                SqlQueries.SELECT_USER.replace("%USERNAME%", username));

        // I am not at all sure what this is supposed to do....
        // If user doesn't exist, block access
        if (!resultSet.next()) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now if an exception is thrown by `DataFiles.getConnection()`, the call method terminates immediately with an exception (the remained is not executed) and the task enters a `FAILED` state. If you need access to the exception in the case that something goes wrong, you can do:

```
LoadingTask loadingTask = new LoadingTask();
loadingTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
    Throwable exc = loadingTask.getException();
    // do whatever you need with exc, e.g. log it, inform user, etc
});
loadingTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    // whatever you need to do when the user logs in...
});
myExecutor.execute(loadingTask);
```